# How to check if li.a tab is active?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class role="presentation"><a href="#tab-aaa" data-toggle="tab">aaa </a></li>
<li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-bbb" data-toggle="tab">bbb </a></li>
<li class role="presentation"><a href="#tab-ccc" data-toggle="tab">ccc </a></li>
</ul>
```

As the code above, bbb tab is active now. How to write jquery to check if ccc tab is active, then do something?

Comment: give id to each li and check which li is active and do what ever you want to do

Comment: Check this example http://www.tutorialspark.com/twitterBootstrap/TwitterBootstrap_Tab_Events_Javascript.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this :

```
$('ul.nav li').click(function() {
   $('ul.nav li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   if($(this).find('a').attr('href') == '#tab-ccc') {
       alert('ccc clicked');
   }
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/hs5L5Ls6/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use jQuery to do that as well:

```
if($('ul.nav li:last-child').hasClass('active')){
// do something
}
```

Unfortunately unless you have class/id on the `li` element you can't specifically select it by its child href value for example.
If you can give them Ids - then you can do something like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li id="aaa" class role="presentation"><a href="#tab-aaa" data-toggle="tab">aaa </a></li>
<li id="bbb" class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-bbb" data-toggle="tab">bbb </a></li>
<li id="ccc" class role="presentation"><a href="#tab-ccc" data-toggle="tab">ccc </a></li>
</ul>
```

And then more specifically select like this:

```
if($('ul.nav li#ccc').hasClass('active')){
// do something
}
```

Here is a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/nvLed1y5/4/

**EDIT**

I actually thought of an even better solution that would be both specific and not require you to add code to your HTML:
If you use a selector and check if it exists, you can tell if the right one is active. Like this:

```
if($('ul.nav li.active a[href="#tab-ccc"]').length > 0){
// do something
}
```

Here's a fiddle for that as well: https://jsfiddle.net/5b40qzkb/1/

Comment: if($('ul.nav li:last-child').hasClass('active')){
 alert('aaas');
} // it is not working.

Comment: if($('ul.nav li#ccc').hasClass('active')){
 alert('aaas');
} // it is not working too.

Comment: In your HTML example, the LI that contains ccc really doesn't have that class. Have you tried moving the active class to that element and trying?

Comment: Did you add the ids to the li tags?

Comment: @zac1987 I included a working fiddle for you in my answer.

Comment: in your fiddle , i click ccc, but not pop up. It is ok, DinoMyte has gave the right answer.

Comment: You never did mention that you needed this condition to be checked on click.